# Should we merge [software] and [poker-tools] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have [software](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) and [poker-tools](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poker-tools) tags both. Are they both point to the same concept? Let's look at example;

- **Poker Software** --> Poker Tracker: It has a database, it keeps a lot of statistics. It's big and it imports data from a lot of web sites.
- **Poker Tools** --> PokerStove: It is a probabilistic, calculator that determines the odds of winning a Texas Hold'em hand using combinatorics.

But, basically, they are both software regardless of the size and complexity. Should we have both tags? Or should we merge them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two examples both obviously relate to software. However, I'd say that poker-tools can cover a variety of tools that aren't software based. For example, Some people prefer pen and paper for many things, and would like to systematically archive their sessions. Using "poker-tools" could refer to a process rather than a software solution.

At the time of writing there are *8xSoftware* tags and *4xPoker-Tools* tags. It's a relevant point to make, but it's perhaps too early to merge these tags.